# hover on element with class added dynamically

Tags: jquery

I use `hover` and `click` events on element if it hasn't class `'disabled'`

```
$('.stars').each(function () {
    var rating = $(this).parent().parent().find('#rating-input').val(),
        $stars = $(this).children();

    if (rating > 0) {
        $stars.filter(':lt(' + rating + ')').addClass('selected');
    }
    if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        $stars.hover(function() {
            var idx = $(this).index();
            $stars.removeClass('selected').slice(0, idx + 1).addClass('selected');
        }, function() {
            var rating = $(this).parent().parent().find('#rating-input').val();
            $stars.removeClass('selected').slice(0, rating).addClass('selected');
        }).click(function() {
            var rating = ($(this).index() + 1);
            $(this).parent().parent().find('#rating-input').val(rating);
        });
    } 
});
```

but class 'disabled' I added dynamically, so `hover` and `click` continue work even after class 'disabled' was added. How to make it work with dynamically added class?

Comment: can you give me an example how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the class is added dynamically, the condition check also should happen dynamically.

One option in such cases is to use event delegation, but in this case I think it will be easier to check the condition in the event handlers

```
$('.stars').each(function () {
    var rating = $(this).parent().parent().find('#rating-input').val(),
        $stars = $(this).children();

    if (rating > 0) {
        $stars.filter(':lt(' + rating + ')').addClass('selected');
    }
    $stars.hover(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return 
        }
        var idx = $(this).index();
        $stars.removeClass('selected').slice(0, idx + 1).addClass('selected');
    }, function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return 
        }
        var rating = $(this).parent().parent().find('#rating-input').val();
        $stars.removeClass('selected').slice(0, rating).addClass('selected');
    }).click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return 
        }
        var rating = ($(this).index() + 1);
        $(this).parent().parent().find('#rating-input').val(rating);
    });
});
```

Comment: No, the problem stays the same.